# If dharma always protects someone , then how would one have to bear the fruits of karma of previous lives?

Tags: karma, dharma, rebirth

It is being said that if one follows the dharma and do the right things , then he will be protected against any mishappening in life.

But It is also said that we have to bear fruits of our karma of previous lives also .

Then how does this makes sense ?
If I am doing the right things , then I am protected against bad happenings in life , but I also have to bear the fruits of my previous lives.  Isn't it contradictory ?

Comment: You're protected from bad things in the future, if you do good dharmic karmas. However, whatever adharma was done by the jivatman in the previous lives, it shall bear the fruit, there's no doubt about it., there's no escaping from prarabdha.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are right. It's not that by following Dharma you will not face any problem in life. If you see Mahabharat, the Dharmaraj Pandavas had to face so many problems in life but still they never gave up on Dharmic principles.

If you don't get any benefit by following Dharma then why to take so much trouble? One should follow Dharma not for protection or benefit but to please the Supreme Lord just like Pandavas did.
Thus without any will/interest or attachment towards Bhagwan, you cannot follow Dharma for long because you are expecting benefit which you might not get always. Therefore, the devotees of Lord, they are the dharmaraj because they don't want to do anything which displeases Him.

***If you want to sustain on Dharmic principles, be a devotee of Lord Krishna.***